# FATAL EXCEPTION! kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to make a program that calculates the price after the user choses the paper type,size, printing colors via radio buttons and inputs how many paper and copies, i got this run time error :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.printonejuc.sarah.test, PID: 8534
>                     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{c260af3 VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090009 app:id/Pages}"
>                         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
>                         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
>                         at com.printonejuc.sarah.test.newOrder$onCreate$1.onClick(newOrder.kt:74)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

newOrder.kt

```
resultTxt.setOnClickListener {

        if ((PaperSize.checkedRadioButtonId != -1) && (PaperSize.checkedRadioButtonId != -1) && (PaperType.checkedRadioButtonId != -1)) {

            if (A4size.isChecked) {
                if (Plain.isChecked && Black.isChecked) {
                    //plain black calculation
                    totalPrice =(1 * PagesI.toInt())*CopiesI.toInt()
                   result.text = "total:  " + totalPrice

                }
```

line 74:

> totalPrice =(1 * PagesI.toInt())*CopiesI.toInt()

Pages and Copies are initialized inside onCreat method and before onClickListner

> ```
>  Pages = findViewById<View>(R.id.Pages)as EditText
>     Copies = findViewById<View>(R.id.Copies) as EditText
> ```

```
    var PagesI = Pages.toString()
    var CopiesI = Copies.toString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `PagesI` and/or `CopiesI` are some sort of `EditText` widgets.

You should not be calling `toInt()` on the widget but the text contained in the widget. Add `.text` before `.toInt()`:

```
totalPrice =(1 * PagesI.text.toInt())*CopiesI.text.toInt()
```

Comment: I've already initilaized it inside on create method like this      Pages = findViewById<View>(R.id.Pages)as EditText
        Copies = findViewById<View>(R.id.Copies) as EditText

        var PagesI = Pages.toString()
        var CopiesI = Copies.toString()

Comment: You're calling `toString()` on the widget, and it returns a string like `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{c260af3 VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090009 app:id/Pages}`. Obtain the `text` property calling conversion on it in your click listener, e.g. `Pages.text.toString().toInt()`